When using openpyxl on linux with LibreOfficeCalc ... boolean cell values get saved as formulas
Using openpyxl, when I save a Boolean value to a cell, the resulting (libreoffice-calc) spreadsheet shows the value as a formula instead of as a Boolean.
cell.value = True
After setting the value, the cell.data_type is 'b', and the cell.value is True.
When I save and then open the spreadsheet with openpyxl and read the cell, the data_type is 'f' with the value being '=True()'
When I open the spreadsheet with libreoffice-calc, the value is the formula =True()
Is this a bug, a feature, or operator error on my part?

Create a new Calc spreadsheet using Libreoffice. Put the value TRUE in cell A1. Save that as *.xlsx. Then open it using Libreoffice again. What do you see in cell A1? For me it is the formula =True(). That is fully independent of openpyxl. Why? Well *.xlsx is not the native file format of Libreoffice. So don't be surprised if it is not fully supported by Libreoffice.
